# Member variable losing value c++ when going out of scope of BeginPlay function Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, member-variables

Unreal Engine 4.23.0
C++

When running the function **BeginPlay()**, my member variable **_initialTransforms** nicely fills in everything as expected, but the moment I'm going out of the scope of the BeginPlay() function and into the DrawRobot(...,...) function _initialTransforms loses its values and just becomes an empty TArray again.
I checked if I accidentally changed its values in another function, but these are the only references of _initialTransforms in the project. The class derives from 'AActor', and the object is created out of a possessed 'pawn'. The object doesn't get recreated since its constructor doesn't run twice. Does anyone have an idea why this happens?
Thank you!

The reduced version of the code below.

### Header file

```
protected:
    TArray<FMatrix> _initialTransforms;
```

### cpp file

```
void ARobot::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    TArray<float> zeroArray;
    zeroArray.Init(0, 6);
    Forward(zeroArray, _initialTransforms);
}

void ARobot::Forward(TArray<float> jointsDeg, TArray<FMatrix>& m)
{...
}

void ARobot::DrawRobot(TArray<float> jointsDeg)
{
    Forward(jointsDeg, _currentPose);

    FTransform baseTransform = FTransform(ToLeftHanded(_currentPose[0] * _initialTransforms[0].Inverse()));
... }
```

Comment: you pass the member by value. You never modify the member

Comment: With the risk of sounding stupid, doesn't the & in the function definition mean that I'm passing a reference? If not, how should I actually modify the member? I need to actually be able to modify the original.

Comment: sorry I though it is about `TArray<float> jointsDeg`. Your code is really hard to grasp becuase it is only fragments. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I just tried it with some dummy values, instead of linking it through another 'pawn', and it actually works. Somehow by running the next line in the other pawn, I'm not pointing to the right object of my ARobot class, I guess.
`SelectedRobot->GetDefaultObject<ARobot>()->DrawRobot(_joints);`

Comment: `GetDefaultObject` is going to return you a static default that won't exist any uworld.

Answer (score 0):

As George mentioned, GetDefaultObject doesn't return the actual object. The function below does, so now I can get and set the members of _spawnedRobot easily.

```
FActorSpawnParameters SpawnParams;
    _spawnedRobot = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<ARobot>(SelectedRobot, location, rotation, SpawnParams);
```